# Angular.js can't focus after state changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Our UI is a little buggy. When we load the page the first time everything works perfectly. When we switch - in our case restaurants - the model is update and we can't focus the input fields. Any idea what's going on here?

We have a video with a little demonstration about what's going on:
https://youtu.be/5IBwtBOZmzs

FILE: restaurant.config.js

```
function RestaurantConfig($stateProvider) {
'ngInject';

$stateProvider
    .state('app.restaurant', {
        abstract:true,
        url: '/restaurants/:id',
        controller: 'RestaurantCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'restaurant/views/index.html',
        resolve: {
            restaurant: function (Restaurants, $stateParams) {
                return Restaurants.get($stateParams.id);
            },
            restaurants: function (Restaurants) {
                return Restaurants.getAll()
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.restaurant.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'restaurant/views/dashboard.html',
        title: 'Restaurant'
    })
    .state('app.restaurant.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'restaurant/views/settings.html',
        title: 'Instellingen'
    })
    .state('app.restaurant.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        controller: 'EditCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'restaurant/views/edit.html',
        title: 'Bewerken'
    });
};

export default RestaurantConfig;
```

FILE: restaurant.controller.js

```
class RestaurantCtrl {
    constructor(restaurant, restaurants, $state) {
        'ngInject';

        this.restaurants = restaurants;
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this._$state = $state;
    }

    restaurantChange() {
        this._$state.go('app.restaurant.dashboard', {id: this.restaurant.id});
    }
}


export default RestaurantCtrl;
```

FILE: settings.controller.js

```
class SettingsCtrl {
constructor(restaurant, restaurants, Restaurants) {
    'ngInject';

    this.restaurants = restaurants;
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this._Restaurants = Restaurants;

    this.restaurant.order_interval = this.convertTime(this.restaurant.order_interval);

    this.restaurant.take_away_hour.from = this.convertTime(this.restaurant.take_away_hour.from);
    this.restaurant.take_away_hour.to = this.convertTime(this.restaurant.take_away_hour.to);

    this.restaurant.shopping_hour.from = this.convertTime(this.restaurant.shopping_hour.from);
    this.restaurant.shopping_hour.to = this.convertTime(this.restaurant.shopping_hour.to);
}

convertTime(input) {
    var output = input.split(':')
    var date = new Date();

    date.setHours(output[0]);
    date.setMinutes(output[1]);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(0);

    return date;
}

saveShoppingHour() {
    this._Restaurants.saveShoppingHour(this.restaurant).then(
        (res) => {
            this.success = res;
        },
        (err) => {
            this.errors = err.data.errors;
        }
    );
}

saveTakeAwayHour() {
    this._Restaurants.saveShoppingHour(this.restaurant).then(
        (res) => {
            this.success = res;
        },
        (err) => {
            this.errors = err.data.errors;
        }
    );
}

saveInterval() {
    this._Restaurants.saveInterval(this.restaurant).then(
        (res) => {
            this.success = res;
        },
        (err) => {
            this.errors = err.data.errors;
        }
    );
}
}

export default SettingsCtrl;
```

The strange thing is when you refresh, it works.
Can somebody help us?

Demian

Comment: There are couple of stackoverflow post which suggest using a directive and adding that directive on the control where you need to focus.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617839/cant-focus-on-angular-form-text-input-after-route-change)

If you can provide a jsfiddle or plnkr would be helpful to see whats going on.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same problem. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

So, we also use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

When you click on the dropdown menu, they keep the focus.
The solution was to remove the dropdown, and write our own implementation.

To find which element is focused:
document.activeElement